# PHP , send control to another code without waiting for execution

Tags: php, redirect, routes

I want to write some kind of Router. But the destination code takes a long time to execute and I don't want to keep this Router waiting for the result.
Let me explain with this little code :

I have this Router.php

```
<?php
   if ($_GET['to'] == 'A') require "A.php";
   else  require "B.php"
?>
```

And now A.php :

```
<?php
   sleep(10);
?>
```

Now I got two different questions :

1-  after calling Router.php with parameter to=A, will my router code wait for A.php? as it has to wait for the response of A.php. So I want to know the next requests coming to Router will wait or the waiting is just in A.php side?

2- Is there any better solution than using require"A.php" for routing and switching control between codes?

Please Help

Comment: are you using any framework ?

Comment: @TarangP No bro.

Comment: I think you are missing the role of the Web Front (Apache, Nginx, php's built-in server, etc.). This is that ingredient which takes care of the multi-threading. Your PHP scripts get invoked without you needing to bother with parallelism of the HTTP requests. Also, PHP will not 'wait' for your `include` to perform: the `include`ed file **becomes** your current PHP execution branch, much like a (synchronous) function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does my router code will wait for A.php?

Yes

---

> So I want to know the next requests coming to Router will wait or the waiting is just in A.php side?

All request are independent of each other.

When the next requests coming, the new Router process will be created and executed.

---

> Is there any better solution than using require"A.php" for routing and switching control between codes?

I think you don't have to write a Router. Because many good router component on [packagist](https://packagist.org) such as [fast-route](https://packagist.org/packages/nikic/fast-route), [klein](https://packagist.org/packages/klein/klein).

You can install it just by [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

By the way using MicroFramework like [Slim](https://packagist.org/packages/slim/slim) is also a good way.

---

Sorry for my bad english, I hope it can help you.